# How to list all the files using shell script present in a specific folder under all the directories those are present in the root directory?

Tags: linux, perl, shell, unix

I want to list all the files that are present in a specific folder under all the present directories present in my root directory.
Say my root directory is `.` and there multiples folders like `a1,b1,c1........a2,b2` are present.
Now in all those folders there is a **specific folder** which is `source/` so that will be like

```
a1/source/
b1/source/
.
.
a2/source/
b2/source/
```

where all the necessary files are present. Can I list all the files in a file that is in the `.` directory by a shell script source file along with their absolute path?

Comment: Am I right? you need to list the contents of those folders with the name **source** that are in the sub-directories?

Comment: Do you want to list files in `source` directories at depth greater than 2? For example files in `a1/a2/a3/source`?

Answer (score 1):

StackOverflow isn't really a "write my code for me" service. But this is really simple in Perl.

Assuming that the `source` directories only ever appear at the same level:

```
my @files = glob '*/source/*';
```

Answer (score 0):

In Perl you could use [`File::Find`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find):

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Basename qw(basename);
use File::Find;

find( \&wanted, '.') ;

sub wanted {
    my $name = $_;    
    my $parent_dir = basename( $File::Find::dir );
    if ( (-f $name) && ( $parent_dir eq "source") ) {
        say $File::Find::name;
    }
}
```